# Macro that can decide template, add other recipients, edit subject line

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I am new to VBA and I want to create an Outlook macro that, based on To field, can decide which template to use, add a specific recipient to CC and BCC field, add a string to the existing subject (eg. "example_subject" --> "confirmation\example_subject").

My efforts have yielded this:

```vb
Sub PO_confirmation()

    Dim myItem As Outlook.mailItem

    Dim recipients As Outlook.recipients
    Dim recipientTo As Outlook.recipient
    Dim recipientCC As Outlook.recipient
    Dim recipientBCC As Outlook.recipient

    Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem


    Set recipientTo = myItem.recipients.Add("AAA@aaa.com")
    recipientTo.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo

    Set recipientCC = myItem.recipients.Add("bbb@aaa.com")
    recipientCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC

    Set recipientBCC = myItem.recipients.Add("ccc@aaa.com")
    recipientBCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC

    initialSubj = myItem.Subject
    myItem.Subject = "RE:ABC-" & initialSubj

    myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Now the problem is the BCC recipient always appear in the To field, I can't tell what went wrong?

Comment: You're continuing to work on, and refine, your code, which is great.  Just an observation: the problem originally had several issues, then subsequent edits have jumped between specific ones.  That's fine if your work is solving specific problems.  If there is more than one issue, though, include them in the question.  You don't want a situation where someone provides an answer to the stated problem and then you change the question to focus on a different problem.  BTW, if you do discover another problem after the question has been answered, just post it as a new question.  Good luck.